# How Can I figure out when cosine = $\frac{2}{\pi}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So I'm doing Mean Value theorem homework which states 
$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ 
So I am trying to find $c$ for $f(x)=\sin x$ over the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. So using the Mean Value theorem I got 
$$f'(c)=\frac{1-0}{\frac{\pi}{2}-0}=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{2}{\pi}$$ 
So since $f'(x)=\cos x$ 
$$\cos(c)=\frac{2}{\pi}$$
but I am having trouble finding the value $c$. Am I right so far, if so how do I find $c$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that the Mean Value theorem states, exactly? Your expression $f'(c)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ is not a "statement".

Comment: It would help if you wrote the problem statement, as it is written

Comment: I think that is $$ f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran thanks, that's what I meant.

Comment: Let's be more precise here: you mean that
$$
f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
**For some** $c \in (a,b)$ if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$.  Now, is it really the case that the question is asking you to find the value of $c$, or is the question simply asking you to prove that one exists?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question the original was a typo. It is asking to find $c$, if it exists. And since it does, I need to find $c$.

Comment: @Kenshin I prematurely submitted the comment.  See the edited version, as it is now.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I understand. So, yeah it is asking me to find the value of $c$.

Comment: The answer isn't anything pretty.  Assuming they want an answer for the value of $c$, they'll be expecting you to calculate $\cos^{-1}(2/\pi)\approx 0.881$ with a calculator.

Comment: @Kenshin is $f'(x)=\sin{x}$ or is $f(x)=\sin{x}$?

Comment: @Kenshin also, for trigonometric functions, use `\sin` and `\cos` rather than `sin` and `cos`

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, that was the answer, thanks a lot! I guess I need to learn more trig identities and what not. Thanks again. And, will do with the formatting.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran yes, you're right, sorry. I guess I kind of rushed the question.

Comment: @Kenshin you can use calculator?

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran yes, I can. I just wasn't aware that inverse cosine of the value of cosine that I wanted would give me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose  that the exercise is: Find   $c$, for  $f(x)=\sin{x}$  with $c\in [0,\frac{π}{2}]$, that satisfied the mean value theorem. Then

**With calculator**: $c=\cos^{-1}(\frac{2}{\pi})$

**Without calculator**: how $[0,1]\subseteq[0,\frac{π}{2}]$ you can choose $[0,1]$ then

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=\sin(1)$$ then

$$\cos{c}=\sin(1)$$
$$\cos{c}=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-1\right)$$
$$c=\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$

Comment: Thanks! That was a lot of help.